# Rename [compose] to [compose-db] due to confusion with [android-jetpack-compose]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Some people use [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose) instead of [android-jetpack-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose). Now there are no questions with the wrong tag, because I and a few other users have to monitor this tag to catch android questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69107068/revisions), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69080970/revisions), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69064105/revisions)).

From the description:

> DO NOT USE FOR THE ANDROID JETPACK COMPOSE

Of course, it partly helps, but not completely, and it also distracts those who really want to use [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose).

I think [compose-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-db) should be clear enough so that [android-jetpack-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose) users can make no mistake. But perhaps you can suggest a better version, since 2 letters may not be enough.

I'm not sure if this helps much, most likely many people will still not look at the description of the tag and will create questions just with [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose). Can we disallow this tag after renaming it?

Comment: In regards to your edit; if we rename/ retag directly, then [[tag:compose]] will cease to exist, so someone will have to create the tag again to make that mistake (and there will be no description). If we create a new [[tag:compose-db]] tag and synonymize, then typing in "compose" will correct to "compose-db", which should help curb the Android questions.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of questions in the [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose) tag that aren't related to Compose DB, so before renaming it to [compose-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-db), we need to clean the tag up. From a very brief glance:

- [Those that](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D%20%5Bcompose%5D%20is%3Aq&searchOn=3) also have the [docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker) tag should be retagged to [docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docker-compose).
- Those related to Pytoolz compose should be retagged to [toolz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toolz)
- The tag just needs to be dropped from those questions that use it for the literal meaning of compose.

Once this is done, we can rename [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose) to [compose-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-db).

Comment: Looks like there might be some questions in [[tag:compose]] that belong in [[tag:function-composition]] too.

Comment: I *think* we should be good to go now, but I might've missed a few.

Comment: That's good enough for me, I'll go ahead with the rename. Thanks for your efforts!