# Synonymize [compose] and [compose.io]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

In digging through some [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose) questions to help the [cleanup effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411382), I discovered that there's a [compose.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose.io) tag, which is an exact duplicate of (an alternate name for) [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose), the database platform.

Can these tags be synonymized?

Burning it outright is also an option (there's only 9 questions tagged with the "io" variant), but since Compose.io seems to have been the official title of the platform at some point, making this a synonym sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose) was renamed to [compose-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-db) as part of this meta [Rename [compose] to [compose-db] due to confusion with [android-jetpack-compose]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/411379/). Therefore I added [compose.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose.io) as a synonym of [compose-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-db) instead.

[compose.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose.io) x 9 → [compose-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compose-db) × 85

I went through the list of questions and made sure that they're all related to Compose DB, so I also went ahead and merged the two tags.